# Making picturebox according to value in textbox

Tags: c#, dynamic, picturebox

**Hello Everyone!** I have a program that **counts** all **President** in column **Position** registered in my database. now I counted it and put it into my Textbox. I want to make a dynamic pictureboxes according to the value in my textbox. how can i do it?

Here's my code now :

```
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PYTHON-PC\PYTHON;Initial Catalog=DBVote;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234");
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public FVotingArea()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();

    private void FVotingArea_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sc.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Position) FROM TableVote WHERE Position='" + "President" + "'", sc);
            Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            TxtCount.Text = count.ToString();

            pb.Parent = this;
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pb.BringToFront();
            pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 50);
            pb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 86);
            pb.Name = "PresPicBox";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

I store my images like this :

```
    public void Add()
    {
        sc.Open();
        try
        {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVote (Position, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, YearLevel, Course, SchoolYear, imgPath, imgImage) VALUES (@position, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @yearlevel, @course, @schoolyear, @imgpath, '" + _pb + "')", sc);
        Param();

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(res > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
                FAdminSet._cleardata = cleardata;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing your images?

Comment: already edited my post. Hope you'll see to it, Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer now. Hope it works for you..

```
    TxtCount.Text = count.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Location = new Point((80 * i) + 5, 30);
                pb.Size = new Size(75, 75);
                pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                pb.ImageLocation = "";
                this.Controls.Add(pb);
                pb.BringToFront();
            };
```

and I hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

First you need an image.

```
var image = new Image.FromFile(@"pathToImage");
```

Then you set your PictureBox's image.

```
pb.Image = image;
```

To do it based on a condition:

```
var imagePath = @"c:/";
if (count == 1)
    imagePath += "whatever";
else if (count == 2)
    imagePath += "whatever2";
else
    imagePath += "whatever3";

var image = new Image.FromFile(imageName);
pb.Image = image;
```

You can build that path however you want but hopefully you see the point.

Comment: Thanks for this Smith, but i need not limit it, maybe i can loop it or something? with the <b>pb</b> codes in it? so that when the textbox is like two or up it will make a number of pictureboxes according to the count in TxtCount.Text.